# react native firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I want to upload image in firebase storage.

This code was followed by watching YouTube.

But <**input**> doesn't work.

I think this code is react code.

How can I make it work in **react native**?

please help me.

thank you for read!

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from './config';

export default function App() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const submitData = () => {

    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'image');

    // 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
    uploadBytes(storageRef, image)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {

    if(e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0])
    }

  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>firebase storage!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />

      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />

      <Button title='button' onPress={submitData}>Upload</Button>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) library.

After installing the library you can use their storage module to upload image. Example-

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

try {
  const bucketFile = '/posts/pic5.png';
  const localFile = 'path/to/local/file.png';
  const storageRef = storage().ref(bucketFile);
  await storageRef.putFile(localFile);
  const url =  await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
  console.log('image url', url);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('firebase upload image error', error);
}
```

You can select local image using image picker libraries like:

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: I already install firebase library! can you upload full code?